# TestContainers Shared Database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, junit, testcontainers

I'm trying to have a single PostgreSQL TestContainer in JUnit 5 that all my test classes extend. Currently, only one of my test classes pass/are tested using this TestContainer, and the rest give me an "Unable to acquire JDBC Connection" error.

This is what my parent class looks like:

```
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = SchemaMigrationApplicationTests.Initializer.class)
public class SchemaMigrationApplicationTests {

    public static final String BC_BASE_DOMAIN = "proxy-si.broadcloudpbx.net";
    public static final String EDOS_PROFILE = "asdf1234";
    public static final Region COUNTRY_REGION = Region.INT;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "postgres";
    private static final String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "postgres";
    private static final String DATABASE_USERNAME = "username";

    @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = (PostgreSQLContainer) new PostgreSQLContainer()
            .withDatabaseName(DATABASE_NAME)
            .withPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD)
            .withUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME)
            .withReuse(true);

    static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
                TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + postgreSQLContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + postgreSQLContainer.getPassword()).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
            
        }
    }
}
```

I simply have my test classes extend SchemaMigrationApplicationTests. I've also tried using a static method and calling .start() on my container in this parent class but that didn't work.

Comment: I think you don't need a reuse option if your field is static and Testcontainers, Container should be removed as well. Can you try that?